# Exception not throw in Writer in Spring Batch when DB query fails

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am using `Spring Batch` for one of my ETL projects. The problem I am facing is during the writer step. Following is the code snippet for it:

```
public void write(List<? extends Employee> employeeList) throws Exception {

    for (Employee emp : employeeList) {
       try {
          employeeService.insertEmployeeBasicDetails(emp);
          employeeService.insertEmployeeCompensationDetails(emp);  
       } catch(Exception e) {
          log.error(e);
       }            
    }
}
```

If I get an error while inserting during the first service call, it does not give an exception but it moves to the second call. After all those calls are done, it throws an error but now there is no catch block to catch the error and my job fails to restart.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your try block 'does not give an exception' because none has been thrown. With the given code, for the write method to throw an uncaught exception it is out of the try block - in this case within catch block. If this is all your code then consider placing a break point within catch block and check that `log.error(e);` does not throw an exception.

Comment: I did add a debugger, it does not reach to the catch block.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting during first call? It'd be appreciated if you'd give more details on how `insertEmployeeBasicDetails` is implemented

Comment: I have included this error just to see everything works fine even if a step fails: Here is the error                                                                                       Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot call methods on varchar.
; SQL []; Cannot call methods on varchar.; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot call methods on varchar.